# Server is not loading new changes in the repository in digital ocean droplet

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean, droplet

We have a setup where we pull the code from GitHub to the digital ocean droplet manually using `git pull` . I can see from the `git logs` latest changes are being pulled into the environment but these are changes are not being served to live hosted site.

This setup was done by any other dev. So I'm not sure how to update these changes to live server
I have tried finding in the docs. but some where it was mentioned to restart the `nginx` to update the changes

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

After trying this command nothing happens. Please anybody can guide what I'm missing. here.

Comment: Is the place (_"file system"_-wise) where the app is mapped in nginx a repo itself? If it iis, what is checked out there?

Comment: the whole repo iteself

Comment: What is checked out? If it is not _the version you want_, then you probably are missing a direct checkout or a merge (depending on workflow)?

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding your point

Comment: Whats about the app. what app your are hosting there , python ?? or etc and is it running on gunicorn

Comment: Yes its running with gunicorn and its a python-django app.

Comment: Then you are on the right direction , just restart the gunicorn as well 
`sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`

Comment: Thanks faisal that was it. its loading the updates now.